# Formatting of child elements seem to affect parent element's formatting in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying the example from W3Schools in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5). I delete the `float: left;` property in the `ul` selector. The horizontal menu (list) displays as a block floated to the left. Then, I delete the `float: left;` now in the `a` selector, and the menu seems to stop being displayed as floated to the left, as the paragraph now starts in a new line.

My question is how does the formatting of elements inside the `ul` element seems to affect how the `ul` displays as a block. It would seem to me that it should not affect it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by this? I'm not understanding sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear, but then, I'm just a beginner. What I am saying is that:
1. I thought that whether the text flows on the right of the `ul` element or not depends only on whether it displays as a floating block, or not.
2. The flow of the text seems to depend on the properties of elements inside the `ul` element.
3. My question is then: how do you then really determine/explain the text flow around the `ul` in this example?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, basically in the example when you float left the browser only allows other things the same 'row' to be on the same line if they have a float as well. When you remove the float this allows the text to shift up to be on the same row. Text can fluidly just fill gaps like that unless you say `display:block` on the text. Type `background:red` on the `ul` tag and you'll see the space that it ocupies. Then remove the float and you'll see that it ocupies less room. Hopefully that's a good explanation?

Comment: But I am talking about the effect of removing the `float:left` in the `a` selector (everything after having removed the `float:left` in the `ul`).